# Fetch XML from database & merge them

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a table in which a column with `xml` datatype has many xmls in following format.

```
 <Hash HashValue = "9738839398923">
     <Element1>
            <childelement1 attribute1 = "..." attribute2 = "...">
            <childelement2 attribute1 = "..." attribute2 = "...">
            <childelement3 attribute1 = "..." attribute2 = "...">
    </Element1>
    <Element2>
           ......
           ......
    </Element2>
</Hash>
```

Now, i want to fetch all this rows from table & merge them. I have done the fetching part & stored it in a Datatable.

For merging, i went to different solutions on this site but i couldn't get the satisfying result.

**Expected Output Format:**

```
    <Hash HashValue = "4972904980">
         .......
         ......
     </Hash>
    <Hash HashValue = "4534543">
         .......
         ......
     </Hash>
   <Hash HashValue = "536456456456">
         .......
         ......
     </Hash>
```

**The closest I got so far is :**

```
<Hash HashValue = "4972904980">
      <Hash HashValue = "4534543">
         .......
         ......
     </Hash>
  </Hash>
```

**Code for above output:**

```
            FileStream file = File.Open(fakePath, FileMode.Create);
            XElement xFileRoot = XElement.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["ColumnName"].ToString());
            XElement xFileChild = XElement.Parse(dt.Rows[1]["ColumnName"].ToString());
            xFileRoot.Add(xFileChild);
            xFileRoot.Save(file);
```

Above code clearly treat the second xml as child of first one which is clearly not my intention.

How to achieve my expected output?

Comment: Try following : XElement root = new XElement("root", dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => XElement.Parse(x.Field<string>("ColumnName"))));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML only allows a single root element. So you need to create that element explicitly - it can't be one of your existing elements.

One way of doing it:

```
        XDocument xDocument = new XDocument();
        var root = new XElement("root");
        xDocument.Add(root);

        root.Add(XElement.Parse("<entry hash='1'/>"));
        root.Add(XElement.Parse("<entry hash='2'/>"));

        var output = string.Join("\r\n", root.Elements());
```

Instead of the two root.Add statements, you should loop over your records.

It's not the most efficient way to create the XML - but then neither is reading the data into a DataTable - so if it is fast enough for you, then it's fine.

Comment: I know that XML should not have multiple root elements but it's the requirement. Thanks for the good workaround & an easy fix.

Comment: what is the significance of last line of code? I don't see any changes in xml if i skip that.

Comment: root.ToString() would include <root>…</root>. The last line only get the inner xml.... which in most cases will just be equal to the concatenated text of the elements, but if someone plays with namespaces etc, it could be different.

Answer (score 1):

For XML to be valid, there must be 1 single root element.

You are adding the next "element" as a child of the root. This makes no sense if the root and child element are the same element.

I suggest you simply make a dummy root element called? rootElement?

```
XmlElement xFileRoot = doc.CreateElement("rootElement");
```

and then

```
foreach(var row in dt.Rows)
{
   XElement xFileChild = XElement.Parse(row["ColumnName"].ToString());
   xFileRoot.Add(xFileChild);
}
```

and for all intents ignore that root element exists.

Your desired outcome in other words is not valid XML.